# Is there a 3.5e book detailing Baldur's Gate circa 1380?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, forgotten-realms, maps

I am playing in a game set in Baldur's Gate in year 1380 and I'm trying to understand the geography of the city and its districts at that time (1372 is also good).

Which books have a map or a description of the districts of the town in that era?

I can only find D&D 2e material (*Volo's Guide to the Sword Coast*) and D&D 5e material (*Murder in Baldur's Gate* and *Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus*), both named in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/82663/when-did-baldurs-gates-outer-city-come-to-be).

I am mostly interested in finding out when the lower city stopped being called Heapside as a whole giving birth to Bloomridge and other districts and when was Twin Song founded, but should the 3.5e material not talk about these things I will ask new questions (or ask Ed Greenwood).

Comment: I don't have a lot of knowledge about lore/forgotten realm/ Faerun/Baldur's Gate, but in the **Dungeons & Dragons 3rd edition** section of this link there's a ton of books: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forgotten_Realms   that might contain some information you seek, perhaps other members could help, but at least you have some books to look into for now.  I think it's fair to say that 3.0 material is ok if it wasn't republishe in 3.5 or if that's the only way to get some info. Player's Guide to Faerûn in 3.5 or  Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting in 3.0 should be a good place to start.

Comment: I've been comparing maps of Faerun because it says on:https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Forgotten_Realms : The Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting for 3rd edition D&D was a book rather than a boxed set like the two previous editions. **It advanced the timeline to 1372 DR**   so perhaphs there is info in that book I'll try to check.

Comment: @MaximeCuillerier I have the book you mention but no, geographic facts are not mentioned there. I was hoping in some novels or in more specific books like Silver Marches or Waterdeep: city of Splendors.

Comment: Sorry I could not provide more help.

Comment: As near as I can find, it predates what you are thinking of. The name change(s) occurred around the time of the Tax Revolts (For which I cannot find a specific date) that created the current group of 4 ruling group. According to a reference on [this page](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Baldur%27s_Gate), that occurred pre 1235 at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that what you are looking for doesn't really exist, as the name change occurred around either the time of the Tax Troubles, or shortly thereafter which would place it pre 1235 at the least, although that is a bit nebulous.

There is a Forgotten Realms [fandom wiki](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Baldur%27s_Gate#History) history summary, notes this for Heapside:

> After Balduran vanished, local farmers took control of the wall's construction and used it to protect their own holds and farmsteads, rather than the harbor.Nearby townsfolk and other outsiders flocked to the fledgling town for protection and the hamlet swelled in size. The walled region of Gray Harbor came to be known as "Old Town", while newly-constructed buildings, between the southern wall and the harbor, were built in the portion thereafter known as "Heapside"

Shortly after this, the Tax Revolt created the current ruling "Dukes", no timeline is given for this:

> Tax Revolt

> The division of the town by its great wall created a schism between the landowners of Old Town and Balduran's former associates, the captains and other seafarers of Gray Harbor. The Old Towners taxed the carts coming north from the harbor, through Baldur's Gate, which led to the ire of the seamen and their eventual refusal to pay.

> As their anger turned to action, the smugglers, pirates and merchants of Heapside breached Baldur's gate and stormed Old Town by force. Just before they laid siege to the keep of High Hall, the four most-senior sea captains argued for the farmer-lords' surrender. After a quick vote, a truce was struck between the two parties and the retired captains were installed as leaders, jokingly known as "Dukes", of the rapidly-growing city that was earnestly renamed Baldur's Gate.

The [Heapside detail](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Baldur%27s_Gate/Heapside) on that same site states:

> The name Heapside originally referred to the entirety of what came to be known as the Lower City of Baldur's Gate. This changed following the events of the Tax Revolts, when the terms "Upper City" and "Lower City" came into use and replaced "Old Town" and "Heapside"

This is corroborated by:

> Following the **founding of the nation of Amn**, trade skyrocketed in Baldur's Gate and the city expanded. This propensity secured the renewed connection between Old Town, which came to be known as the Upper City, and Heapside, now called the Lower City.

I bolded the Amn section, as the nation of Amn was founded following the collapse of the Shoon Imperium, which was around 450 DR:

> The Shoon Imperium only had one general at the time of it's fall who was native to the Emirate of Amin and not a Calishite. This general was named Esmel Torlath. His was the most successful campaign of all the former Shoonites to rule over the region. Though General Torlath only managed to exert his rule over the western half of the Emirate, this meant that he controlled the biggest, and most well-established cities in the region - Athkatla, Crimmor, and Murann[6] (though land trade between Crimmor and Murann was blocked by ogres in the Small Teeth Mountains).[8] Setting himself up as King Esmel I, he named his kingdom Amn.

I have found a couple of other sources that echo the same text, and haven't found anything to contradict it in any of the 2e or 3.5e source material (Including PDF scans of the box sets).